# Visual Studio 2022 custom template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Is it possible to remove both namespace {} from Visual Studio template so the class will look like this when generated:

```
namespace X;
public class Class1
{
}
```

I changed the file content from **\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class** and now it looks like this

```
namespace $rootnamespace$;
class $safeitemrootname$
{
}
```

but when creating a new class it looks like this

```
namespace X
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but there are _dozens_ of almost-identical `.cs` files in the template directory, so I think you edited a file template used by a different project-type (e.g. C# ASP.NET Core and C# Console Projects use different item templates), so you'll need to edit **all** of them. Have fun.

Comment: I only want to change it for class and interface. Does it matter?

Comment: Yes, this helped me. Thank you